# Why this is making two queries instead of one?

Tags: python, django

View:

```
transfer_details = TransferDetail.objects.filter(user=request.user).select_related('transfermethod_set')

print transfer_details.filter(method__name='PayPal')
```

Models:

```
class TransferMethod(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...


class TransferDetail(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()
    ...
    method = models.ForeignKey(TransferMethod)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I expect transfer_details QuerySet from line one to be used without further database calls.

What I am missing?

**UPDATE 1**

So I discovered when I have these two lines there are no additional queries:

```
    x = transfer_details.filter(method__name='PayPal')
    x2 = transfer_details.filter(method__name='Something')
```

But when I add the following two lines, it's making 2 DB queries:

```
    list(x[:1])
    list(x2[:1])
```

What's happening under the hood and how I can avoid the extra calls?

**UPDATE 2**

I tried:

```
transfer_details.get(method__name='PayPal').data
...
```

It's also making two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correctly it should be (assuming you also want to get the user data in one query):

```
transfer_details = TransferDetail.objects.filter(
    user=request.user).select_related('method', 'user')
```

You wouldn't need to select `method` because when you filter for it in `print transfer_details.filter(method__name='PayPal')` it should get selected automatically. When you call `print` `TansferDetail`'s `__unicode__` will get invoked, so a reason for additional could be that you're outputting some other related data there (eg. from the `User`model, which should be solved with the code above...).

To answer your edited question: If you call `list` on a queryset the queryset gets [evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated), which means the actual query is made.

Don't know if you are accessing `request.user` at some point before in your code, but if that is not the case it's possible that the second query is the result of getting the user for the current request.